# Wordpress set object terms not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set the terms of a custom taxonomy programmatically.

So here is the code I have..

```
$test = wp_set_post_terms(11452, 189,'jobs_sub_categories_taxonomy', false);
```

Now normally the postid and the term id would be fetched from elsewhere but for the test I have entered it in. What I get in return is:

```
var_dump($test);

array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "189" }
```

Now from looking at the Codex an array should list what has been changed. However when I look at the post through the dashboard the custom category isn't checked "on". Am I missing something here?

Comment: what do you mean by **he custom category isn't checked "on"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read further down the page in the codex over [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms), you will see that the term needs to be an array.

```
<?php wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ) ?>
```

Here is the explanation

```
$tag = '5'; // Wrong. This will add the tag with the *name* '5'.
$tag = 5; // Wrong. This will also add the tag with the name '5'.
$tag = array( '5' ); // Wrong. Again, this will be interpreted as a term name rather than an id.

$tag = array( 5 ); // Correct. This will add the tag with the id 5.

wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: Thanks, working now :) I shall mark as solved when I can!